# hadoop: reduce happened between flush map output and finish spill before maps done

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm new to hadoop, and i'm trying the examples wordcount/secondsort in src/examples.

wordcount test environment:

input:

file01.txt

file02.txt

secondsort test environment:

input:

sample01.txt

sample02.txt

Which means both the two test would have 2 paths to process.
I print some log info trying to understand the process of map/reduce.

See what's between **Starting flush of map output** and **Finished spill 0**:
the wordcount program has another two reduce task before a final reduce while 
the secondsort program just do the reduce once and it's done.
Since these programs are so "small", i dont think the io.sort.mb/io.sort.refactor would affect this.

Can anybody explain this?

Thanks for your patience for my broken Englisth and the long log.

These are the log info (i cut some useless info to make it short):

```
wordcount log:

[hadoop@localhost ~]$ hadoop jar test.jar com.abc.example.test wordcount output
13/08/07 18:14:05 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
13/08/07 18:14:06 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local_0001
13/08/07 18:14:06 INFO util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code 0
...
13/08/07 18:14:06 INFO mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 1
13/08/07 18:14:06 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
13/08/07 18:14:06 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
13/08/07 18:14:06 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
Mapper: 0 | Hello Hadoop GoodBye Hadoop
13/08/07 18:14:06 INFO mapred.MapTask: **Starting flush of map output**
Reduce: GoodBye
Reduce: GoodBye | 1
Reduce: Hadoop
Reduce: Hadoop | 1
Reduce: Hadoop | 1
Reduce: Hello
Reduce: Hello | 1
13/08/07 18:14:06 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local_0001_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
13/08/07 18:14:06 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:8020/user/hadoop/wordcount/file02.txt:0+28
13/08/07 18:14:06 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local_0001_m_000000_0' done.
13/08/07 18:14:06 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@4d16ffed
13/08/07 18:14:06 INFO mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 1
13/08/07 18:14:06 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
13/08/07 18:14:06 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
13/08/07 18:14:06 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
13/08/07 18:14:06 INFO mapred.MapTask: **Starting flush of map output**
Reduce: Bye
Reduce: Bye | 1
Reduce: Hello
Reduce: Hello | 1
Reduce: world
Reduce: world | 1
Reduce: world | 1
13/08/07 18:14:06 INFO mapred.MapTask: **Finished spill 0**
13/08/07 18:14:06 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local_0001_m_000001_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
13/08/07 18:14:06 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:8020/user/hadoop/wordcount/file01.txt:0+22
13/08/07 18:14:06 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local_0001_m_000001_0' done.
13/08/07 18:14:06 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@1f3c0665
13/08/07 18:14:06 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/08/07 18:14:06 INFO mapred.Merger: Merging 2 sorted segments
13/08/07 18:14:06 INFO mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 2 segments left of total size: 77 bytes
13/08/07 18:14:06 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
Reduce: Bye
Reduce: Bye | 1
Reduce: GoodBye
Reduce: GoodBye | 1
Reduce: Hadoop
Reduce: Hadoop | 2
Reduce: Hello
Reduce: Hello | 1
Reduce: Hello | 1
Reduce: world
Reduce: world | 2
13/08/07 18:14:06 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
...
13/08/07 18:14:07 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=5
13/08/07 18:14:07 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=6
13/08/07 18:14:07 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
13/08/07 18:14:07 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=5
13/08/07 18:14:07 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
13/08/07 18:14:07 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=8

secondsort log info:

[hadoop@localhost ~]$ hadoop jar example.jar com.abc.example.example secondsort output
13/08/07 17:00:11 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
13/08/07 17:00:11 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
13/08/07 17:00:12 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local_0001
13/08/07 17:00:12 INFO util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code 0
13/08/07 17:00:12 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@57d94c7b
13/08/07 17:00:12 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
13/08/07 17:00:12 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
13/08/07 17:00:12 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
Map: 0 | 5 49
Map: 5 | 9 57
Map: 10 | 19 46
Map: 16 | 3 21
Map: 21 | 9 48
Map: 26 | 7 57
... 
13/08/07 17:00:12 INFO mapred.MapTask: **Starting flush of map output**
13/08/07 17:00:12 INFO mapred.MapTask: **Finished spill 0**
13/08/07 17:00:12 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local_0001_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
13/08/07 17:00:12 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/08/07 17:00:12 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local_0001_m_000000_0' done.
13/08/07 17:00:12 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@f3a1ea1
13/08/07 17:00:12 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
13/08/07 17:00:12 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
13/08/07 17:00:12 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
Map: 0 | 20 21
Map: 6 | 50 51
Map: 12 | 50 52
Map: 18 | 50 53
Map: 24 | 50 54
...
13/08/07 17:00:12 INFO mapred.MapTask: **Starting flush of map output**
13/08/07 17:00:12 INFO mapred.MapTask: **Finished spill 0**
13/08/07 17:00:12 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local_0001_m_000001_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
13/08/07 17:00:12 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/08/07 17:00:12 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local_0001_m_000001_0' done.
13/08/07 17:00:12 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@cee4e92
13/08/07 17:00:12 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/08/07 17:00:12 INFO mapred.Merger: Merging 2 sorted segments
13/08/07 17:00:12 INFO mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 2 segments left of total size: 1292 bytes
13/08/07 17:00:12 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
Reduce: 0:35 -----------------
Reduce: 0:35 | 35
Reduce: 0:54 -----------------
... 
13/08/07 17:00:12 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
13/08/07 17:00:12 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/08/07 17:00:12 INFO mapred.Task: Task attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0 is allowed to commit now
13/08/07 17:00:12 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: Saved output of task 'attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0' to output
13/08/07 17:00:12 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
13/08/07 17:00:12 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0' done.
13/08/07 17:00:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%
13/08/07 17:00:13 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local_0001
13/08/07 17:00:13 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 22
13/08/07 17:00:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Output Format Counters 
13/08/07 17:00:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Written=4787
...
13/08/07 17:00:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=236
13/08/07 17:00:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=92
```

**PS: The main()s for others to check out.**

wordcount:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     JobConf conf = new JobConf(test.class);
     conf.setJobName("wordcount");

     conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
     conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

     conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
     conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
     conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

     conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
     conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

     FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
     FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

     JobClient.runJob(conf);
   }
```

secondsort:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = new Job(conf, "secondarysort");
        job.setJarByClass(example.class);
        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
        job.setPartitionerClass(FirstPartitioner.class);
        job.setGroupingComparatorClass(GroupingComparator.class);

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntPair.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine output records=6

This says it all: the reduce function is used both as a combiner and a reducer. So what you are seeing is output from the combiner. The combiner is (sometimes) invoked when output is spilled.

I think you should have added your code, at least the part in the main() to show us how your job is set up. This would make it easier to answer your questions.

Comment: If you do not want any combining remove the following line from your main: `conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);`

Answer (score -1):

I think the lines such as

> Reduce: GoodBye
>
> Reduce: GoodBye | 1

are `println(...)`in your source codes, and you need to check the source code.